# How to use XUnit Schema?

Tags: c#, xunit

Please can someone assist me in how to integrate the XUnit schema to avail of the **stopOnFail** functionality.

I would like to stop the execution my unit tests if one fails.

By looking at:https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files

Please correct me where I am wrong but I have:

1. Added a new file to the root of my test project: **xunit.runner.json**
2. Updated the .csproj file of my test project to include:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="xunit.runner.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

3. I have added the entire contents of: `https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json` to my **xunit.runner.json** and updated the **stopOnFail** to the following:

```
"stopOnFail": {
    "description": "Enable or disable stopping running further tests once a failed test has been recorded.",
    "default": true,
    "type": "boolean"
}
```

This is not working, can someone advise me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: try just `"stopOnFail": true`

Comment: to where just to the schema(so remove desc, default and type?) and nothing else? didnt work -> 'value must be one of the following types: object'

Comment: I missed the part where you copied schema json. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78157318/2892829) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misread the documentation, so let's read it again.

Step 1 states:

> Add a new JSON file to the root of your test project. Name the file xunit.runner.json. Start with a schema reference so that text editors (like Visual Studio & Visual Studio Code) can provide auto-complete behavior while editing the file

That means starting with a `xunit.runner.json` file that contains the *url* to the schema file, not the schema file's contents:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json"
}
```

The JSON schema for the configuration file isn't a valid configuration file in itself, don't use it like that. The `$schema` property is just there so editors know where to look for the schema so they can help you with validation.

Then, if you keep reading, you'll see that the `stopOnFail` property is a boolean with a default value of `false`. So, to enable it, you just need to set it to `true`. The result is the following configuration file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json",
  "stopOnFail": true
}
```

And then, you have to make sure your runner supports the feature, as it was added in version 2.5.0.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write that out, unfortuantely it didnt work, is there anyway to break this down to test and find why its not working? for example do I need to ref the file anywhere in the test.cs class? (using .net6 if that is needed)

Comment: I dont know if it matters but worth mentioning I have followed the instrucitons to implement ordering of unit tests incase that is in some way conflicting with this? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/order-unit-tests?pivots=xunit

Comment: XUnit assumes the `xunit.runner.json` file is next to the assembly containing your tests. That's why you have to add it to the `.csproj`  with `CopyToOutputDirectory`, so that it gets copied next to the assembly.

Comment: That said, looks there was a bug like disabling parallelism also disables `stopOnFail` (https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/issues/392) that was since fixed. What version of XUnit are you using?

Comment: xunit" Version="2.6.3"... xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5"

Comment: Ah! As explained in the documentation, `stopOnFail` is supported on "Runners v2 2.5+", so you need to update `xunit.runner.visualstudio` to at least 2.5.0. Your version is almost 2 years old at this point.

Comment: ahh good spot...Thank you kindly good sir! you have helped me when you didnt have to.

Answer (score 0):

The `xunit.runner.json` file included next to lines must be enough. (more information [here](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files#stopOnFail)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json",
  "stopOnFail": true
}
```

Comment: No, you should _not_ copy the schema contents inside the configuration file, schemas are not data.